# Json writes for a superclass in scala

Tags: json, scala

```
trait PropertyType {
  def price: Double
}

case class House(price: Double, noOfBedRooms: Short) extends PropertyType

object House{
  implicit val houseReads: Reads[House] = (
    (JsPath \ "price").read[Double] and
    (JsPath \ "noOfBedRooms").read[Short]
  )(House.apply _)


  implicit val houseWrites: Writes[House] = (
    (JsPath \ "price").write[Double] and
    (JsPath \ "noOfBedRooms").write[Short]
  )(unlift(House.unapply))

   implicit val format = Format(houseReads,houseWrites)
 }

case class Land(price: Double,area: Double) extends PropertyType

object Land{
  implicit val landWrites: Writes[Land] = (
    (JsPath \ "price").write[Double] and
    (JsPath \ "area").write[Double]
  )(unlift(Land.unapply))
```

}

```
case class Property(owner: String, propertyType: PropertyType)<---
```

PropertyType has 2 subclases House and Land

```
object Property{

  implicit val propertyWrites: Writes[Property] = (
    (JsPath \ "owner").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "propertyType").write[PropertyType] <---
  )(unlift(Property.unapply))

}
```

How can i implement the Writer for Property so that i can use both House and Land objects  as a PropertyType ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide a `Writes` instance for `PropertyType` within your `Property` object, that pattern matches the actual type to be written:

```
object Property {

    implicit object PropertyTypeWrites extends Writes[PropertyType] {
        override def writes(pt: PropertyType): JsValue = pt match {
          case l: Land => Json.toJson(l)(Land.landWrites)
          case h: House => Json.toJson(h)(House.houseWrites)   
        }
    }

    implicit val propertyTypeReads: Reads[PropertyType] =
        JsPath.read[Land].map(x => x: PropertyType) orElse
            JsPath.read[House].map(x => x: PropertyType)

    implicit val propertyWrites: Writes[Property] = ...
}
```

**EDIT**: added reads instance for `PropertyType`

Comment: if i use Option[fieldName] the type of the subclass cannot b determined and the Reads and Writes will not work as expected.. i am so lost here .. if u can show me a way!!!

Comment: What do you mean by Option[fieldName]? Can you post the relevant pieces of code?

Comment: modified case classes are

`case class House(price: Double, noOfBedRooms: Option[Short]) extends PropertyType`

`case class Land(price: Double,area: Option[Double]) extends PropertyType`

when i post 

`{"owner":"ownername","propertyType":"price":12313.0,"noOfBedRooms":4}}`
 
the reader is reading it as 
`{"owner":"ownername","propertyType":{"price":12313.0}}`
and for as `{"owner":"ownername","propertyType":"price":12313.0,"area":411.1231}}` 
as 
`{"owner":"ownername","propertyType":"price":12313.0,"area":411.1231}}`

Comment: The problem with changing `noOfBedRooms` and `area` to be an `Option` is that Reads are now ambiguous. A `House` may be parsed as a `Land` (or vice versa, depending on the order) since only the `price` field is mandatory. One possible solution would be to introduce a discriminator property within the serialization as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/7UFcWWm7ZSQ). Since I wouldn't like to edit the answer anymore you can check the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/edgarmueller/584c3d1faa933a4cb568) which should give you an impression how to do that.